# How to log exceptions within kotlin predicates?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given something like:

```
fun List<Something>.getWidget(): MyWidget = 
    first { widget ->
        // widget getting code here
    }
```

I want to catch and log the possible NoSuchElementException. What's the best way to do this within a predicate?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do it within predicate? You are missing something here.. It would be better if you give us the `widget getting code here`  part ... Basically, the predicate will return a boolean you can just enclose the function within try/catch

Comment: `    first { widget ->
         widget.property == value &&
         widget.otherProperty.contains(someOtherValue)
    }'

Answer (score 3):

Is this maybe what you want?

```
fun List<Something>.getWidget(): MyWidget = 
    try {
        first { widget ->
            // widget getting code here
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchElementException) {
        //do whatever you want here, like logging
        throw e //rethrow it
    }
```

Although I maybe think you misunderstand what `NoSuchElementException` actually means. That exception doesn't happen in the predicate. It is thrown when for none of the `Something` objects the predicate is true

Comment: tried that - type mismatch:  should be a Boolean but instead finds Unit

Comment: @lstephenpost that would be an error in your predicate that I didn't write then and already existing before

Answer (score 0):

The `first` function throws if it doesn't find an element matching the predicate, so @IvoBeckers 's answer is what you want (wrap the whole call in a try/catch). But you might just want to use `firstOrNull` instead, if you're handling the missing item case and not just letting it crash (which would log the stacktrace anyway)

```
fun List<Something>.getWidget(): MyWidget = 
    firstOrNull { widget ->
        // widget getting code here
    } ?: defaultWidget.also { Log.w("ohno") }
```